# How to write out line of error for error exception (as well as actual error) in Python

Tags: python, csv, encoding, utf-8, stack-trace

I am running a script that fails a lot on cron jobs. It has issues with encoding (UTF etc) that I'm trying to sort and get my head around. I've made it so that the script writes its errors out to a csv when they crop up, which it does fine, but it doesn't tell me which line the error is happening on, so I am struggling to find out where to put some `.encode('utf-8')` in to sort out the problem. Can anyone tell me if there's a way to add to my error writing function to get the line of the error too?

The function I use to catch errors (for other bits of code too) is as follows...

```
def error_output(error):
    t = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    new_data = [t, error]
    f = open('outputs/errors.csv', 'a')
    csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n').writerows([new_data])
    f.close()
```

...and the script uses it thus:

```
if some condition:
    try:
        something
    except Exception as e:
        error_output(e)
```

...this works nicely to give me a CSV that tells me things like:

```
2017-08-19 23:58:47 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 69: ordinal not in range(128)
2017-08-20 00:10:46 Failed to send request: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position 136: invalid continuation byte
```

...but what I'd like is to get more than just the technical description of the error, I'd like to know where in the code it is happening, because I've peppered all my strings with `.encode('utf-8')` and it still fails like this so I need to know where the error is specifically (much as I would if I was running the script from the terminal - which I sometimes do, but the error only happens some of the time, likely when dealing with strange characters or emoji etc.).

Any help massively appreciated as it's a frustrating issue. Thanks!

Comment: Hi. I know this doesn't directly answer your problem but why don't you try to use a debugger and step through the lines of the problematic function - at each step you'd be able to see the values of variables and you'd see at which place you get an exception. Hope that helps :) (I use PyCharm for development which provides a debugging interface)

Comment: Instead of the function you can use logging - https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html. No need to rewrite tools that are working. As for the location see the answer Danil gave you.

Comment: Thanks for the comments both but due to a longer story this is the way I need to solve this particular problem as the script needs to keep running constantly and I just want to catch the error in the meantime. In future I will try to use logging though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `traceback`

```
>>> import traceback
>>> 
>>> def f():
...     if True:
...         1 / 0
... 
>>> try:
...     f()
... except:
...     print(traceback.format_exc())
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in f
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

Comment: Looks promising. Can I assign traceback.format_exc() to a variable and write that out with my csv?

Comment: Is there a way I can mitigate problems with the \n ? It seems that now this causes the logger function to break.

Comment: Yeah, it hasn't actually worked at all unfortunately. Not sure why as the logging fails if I import and use traceback. Back to square one! If I could avoid the \n it might write properly to my file...

Comment: Can I get the variable as follows?: traceback_info = traceback.format_exc()

Comment: Got it! Thanks @danil-speransky

Answer (score 1):

You should really use [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) and add to the formatter - `%(lineno)d`

something like:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(lineno)d %(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('This message should appear on the console')
logging.info('So should this')
logging.warning('And this, too')
```

If you need it in a file read about [`FileHandler`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#filehandler). This technique will also benefit you in the future.